# Which JRE version does LibreOffice require

Tags: catalina, java, libreoffice

LibreOffice readme 7.4 states needs JRE for full functionality?

Which JRE would it need?

Which JRE does Catalina require? Or does one just install JDK?'

OpenJDK works with LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is bordering on off topic, but to address the Apple relevant question….

> Which JRE does Catalina require? Or does one just install JDK?'

Catalina doesn’t require a JRE. macOS has no need for a Java Runtime Environment out of the box. You would install a JRE/JDK based on **your**  needs/requirements.

Now, since you mentioned LibreOffice, a quick look at their [System Requirements for macOS](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/system-requirements/#Apple) tells you what you need:

> Due to an issue, there are the following restrictions with Java: on macOS 10.10 and newer, **JRE isn't found, JDK is required**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

*You need the JDK*.

[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org) is the Open Source implementation of *Oracle’s Java Platform, Standard Edition*. It’s the same thing as the fully licensed Java Platform. So, in short, it works with all Java apps including LibreOffice.

Comment: So that is where they put it, as it was not in release notes or readme.

Comment: Did not want to install wrong Java version and have Apple complain.

Comment: Always check the “Systems Requirements” page for software you’re interested in.  This is pretty standard. “Release notes” are for issues about that particular release version.  For what it requires to work, you need to see the Systems Requirements which is typically found in the Installation docs.

Comment: Should any JDK version work, as this is defined in LibreOffice system requirements?

Comment: You always want the latest JRE/JDK as it ensures the latest security updates.